# Interoperability Beween Unity and Agora.io Web SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

It is possible to connect the web sdk of agora.io, and get the video sources using Unity?? i need a client side with a simple browser Link for my end users to log in a channel and publish a stream, but then i need the vide in Unity to process video and develop an interactive experience.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! As long as the web app and Unity app share the same app id and the channel name, you are good to go.  In Unity, make sure you call this method to have the best compatibility:

*[EnableWebSdkInteroperability](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#a8a29b730ea8847ad8fa56174f3b7e848)*():